# Want to make smaller size list around a maximum value of a big list

Tags: python

I want to make a smaller size list around a maximum value of a big list. How can I do that efficiently using python.

```
tmp=[11, 22, 13, 45 ,21, 56, 26, 9, 10, 89, 77, 34, 91, 65, 67] 
max_val=max(tmp) 
max_index=tmp.index(max_val) 
print max_index,i,max_val
```

In this list, the index and the maximum value and those are 13 and 91. I want a list around the index 13 of width 2 i,e [77, 34, 91, 65, 67]

Best
Sudipta

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea what you are talking about.  Maybe if you told us how you intend to use this, or showed some code?

Comment: do you know where the maximum is?

Comment: Before the down voters come, I would recommend adding code that you have already tried. Remember, research your questions *before* you ask them!

Comment: I can think of a couple ways to interpret your question. Make a single small (say 100 items) list out of the first few items of a bigger list: `smalllist = biglist[:100]`; Make many small lists containing all items of the original list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/312464#312464 .  Do you mean something else? You should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> tmp = [11, 22, 13, 45 ,21, 56, 26, 9, 10, 89, 77, 34, 91, 65, 67]
>>> idx = tmp.index(max(tmp))
>>> tmp[idx-2:idx+3]
[77, 34, 91, 65, 67]
```

Comment: If i save this new list in a new variable then what will be the new index? i,e tmp1=tmp[idx-2:idx+3] then their index will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

Comment: Remember that in Python, things are 0-indexed. That is, you count starting at 0. temp.index(91) → 12, so in the old list, the index of the maximum is 12, or 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 if you included the ones around it. In the new list, the indexes in the new list would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @KeJi you should probably include checks to make sure `indx >= 2`

Comment: `tmp[max(0, idx-2): idx+3]` in case idx < 2